# Regular Expressions: Capturing repeating blocks within given delimiters (in MATLAB)

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm trying to capture a set of variable names within a string, delimited by some specific character at the beginning and end of the string. Something like this:

```
" {var1  var2  var3} ", or
" [var1  var2  var3] "
```

You can easily capture all of them as an array of strings. Something like this does the trick:

```
out = regexp(str, '(?<varname>\w*)', 'names')
```

Matlab returns an array of structs with one field called "varname".

The problem is, this will work whatever the delimiters are. How would you capture the variable names when, say, the delimiters are '{' and '}' but not otherwise? Something like:

```
out = regexp(str, '\{(?varname>\w*)\}', 'names')
```

won't work.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp, you could match the text by trying to match \{(\w*\W*)*\}, similar to what you have, but MATLAB doesn't support quantified captures so you can't just pull out the \w* part via a capture.

Would the following be sufficient?

```
>> str = " {var1  var2  var3} "
>> str = extractBetween(str,"{","}");
>> str = split(str)

str = 

  3×1 string array

    "var1"
    "var2"
    "var3"
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, matlabbit. I can also call the regexp function twice, once in order to extract whatever is inside the {} and another one to capture the variable names from the output of the first regexp call. That's actually the workaround that I have implemented. But I was hoping there would be a cleaner solution with one single regexp call.